# Ember and Native Javascript Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, w2ui

I have an Ember app that uses several third party jQuery Library. One of those is W2ui for creating robust tables. I initialize these tables inside didInsertElement hook. Tables render nicely except that buttons are not working properly. One example is here:

```
<table onclick="var el=w2ui['gridAlerts_toolbar']; console.log(el); el.click('add', event);"> ... </table>
```

The console.log above is working but The problem is that Ember seems to be interfering the third party library event listeners. the el.click method seems to get lost somewhere. If I use the library outside Ember, it works properly. My question is how can I properly incorporate a big third party library (that has own actions and listeners) into Ember. I hope you can direct me to right direction. Thanks.

Comment: is `el` an element or a jQuery collection when logged? if the first, use `$(el)` instead

Comment: Hi @dandavis `el` is a collection of functions and objects. `el` is generated by the third party library so I think I cannot really changed it... i just use the inspector that why I see this. By the way here is the screen shot of the log:  [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/5b5012d5c3.png)
Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining the click events? Can you share code snippet? I'm looking at the docs as an example: http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2grid.onClick